# what is really working solution for armpit sweat

Tags: sweat

Is there anything that actually prevents armpit sweat?

Comment: As written, your question was off topic because it's a request for personal medical advice, so I edited it to comply with site rules. However, it's not clear to me if you're asking how to prevent sweat or how to prevent body odor, so I took a guess. You can correct my edits if I guessed wrong, but please keep the question general and not about you specifically.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate

Answer (score -1):

Solutions to managing armpit sweat and odor:
1) Shave your armpits once every few months to periodically clear out that persistent bacteria. 
2) Sprits or dampen armpits with diluted alcohol solution to kill the bacteria (don’t do this immediately after shaving).
3) Apply adhesive armpit pads to your favorite shirts, so as to prevent bacteria and deodorant buildup in them. 
4) Consult with your doctor before doing any of these, except #3.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a *strict policy* that all answers should be backed up with reliable references, in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background.
See [this list](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references) of reliable sources for inspiration. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: The above isn't meant as criticism of content, merely on form. Content wise, however, I have to add that shaving does *not* "clear out" bacteria. (Shortening those hairs is not useless though: it reduces the surface area where they might grow etc…)